# spree commerce in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am newbie to Ruby on Rails and I would like to install "Spreecommerce". Could I have some help on doing this? I don't know where to start. Any help will be highly appreciable, thanks!

Comment: Very unspecific question which is more or less impossible to answer here.

Answer (score 7):

You are talking about [Spreecommerce](http://spreecommerce.com/download). Next time, try to add a link to the project/gem/plugin you are talking about.

Install the gem, on the command line like this:

```
gem install spree
```

Or, go to the Gemfile of your project and add the following line:

```
gem 'spree'
```

Then type this in the command line:

```
bundle install
```

Then, go to the [official github](https://github.com/spree/spree) page and read the documentation of this gem to get more information about it and how to use it. There is also this official [getting started page](http://spreecommerce.com/documentation/getting_started.html) that you need to read.